# using UIImageView to show correct image size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, ios6

how do you use UiimageView to show an image to make sure the imageview is the correct size of the UIImage? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should create an imageView with the frame of your image automatically.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName"]];
```

A little background from the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/initWithImage%3a).

> This method adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the
>   specified image. It also disables user interactions for the image view
>   by default.

Comment: how do I change the position of it though? Like the x and y position?

Comment: You can either use the `imageView.center` property to adjust its position or set the `imageView.frame` property and only pass in x and y like so: `[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0,100.0,imageView.frame.size.width,imageView.frame.size.height)];`